# How to combine fixed n rows into columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula

I have a Report (Crystal Reports) which is feeded records in the following way;

|FieldName|Value|Position|
|-------|------|-------|
|'Name'|'Anton'|01|
|'Age'|15|02|
|'Gender'|'X'|03|
|'Name'|'Anton'|04|
|'Age'|15|05|
|'Gender'|'M'|06|
|'Name'|'Anton'|07|
|'Age'|15|08|
|'Gender'|'M'|09|
etc, etc,

So my recordset has only 3 columns, FieldName, Value and Position.
I've created an formula which put all the rows in a variable like:

```
if record.Position = 1 then stringVar name_1 = record.Value
if record.Position = 2 then StringVar age_1 = record.Value
if record.Position = 3 then StringVar gender_1 = record.Value
```

and so on for the second, third, ... record

If I put this formula in the detail section, then all the variable are created.
Then I create a new formula for each individual variable created and put for example name_1, age_1 and gender_1 in a footer section, name_2, age_2, gender 2 in a second footer section and so on.

My question is;
Is it possible to put these records in some kind of an array to itterate this array as a normal recordset with 3 column? So in pseude; create array with 3 columns of first 3 records and so on?
Purpuse is to use this array in the detail section to create an layout with 3 columns for the corresponding 3 records, so first row is record 1..3, second row = 4..6, third row = record 7..9 and so on.

Comment: Your best bet is to use code outside Crystal to convert the text input to a csv, excel, or database table that Crystal can use as-is. 

Doing this in Crystal would require two reports (or a main report, UFL function, and a subreport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the image below shows, this Crystal formula can convert your data to the desired display as a single text object. But if you need to handle the data as a regular multi-row result set, you would need a 2-step process.

[image]

```
local stringvar Data_In_Rows := {@Data} ;
Data_In_Rows := Replace(Data_In_Rows, "|FieldName|Value|Position| |-------|------|-------| |'Name'|","");
Data_In_Rows := LEFT(Data_In_Rows, Len(Data_In_Rows) - 1) ;
Data_In_Rows := Replace(Data_In_Rows, "| |'Name'|", Chr(10) + Chr(13));
Data_In_Rows := Replace(Data_In_Rows, "'Age'|", "");
Data_In_Rows := Replace(Data_In_Rows, "'Gender'|", "");
local stringvar array myArray := Split(Data_In_Rows, Chr(10) + Chr(13));
local stringvar result ;
local numbervar NumberOfRows := UBound(myArray) ;
local numbervar rowNumber;
local stringvar row ;
local stringvar array rowArray;
For rowNumber := 1 to NumberOfRows step 1 do
(
row := myArray[rowNumber];
rowArray := Split(row, "| |");
IF UBound(rowArray) = 3 Then
result := result + LEFT(rowArray[1], Len(rowArray[1]) -3 ) + "," + LEFT(rowArray[2], Len(rowArray[2]) -3 ) + "," +LEFT(rowArray[3], Len(rowArray[3]) -3) + Chr(10) + Chr(13);
);
result := "Name,Age,Gender" + Chr(10) + Chr(13) + result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. What do you mean with a 2-step proces? What I need is a result like showed in your image, (RHb section) but then as a regular multirow recordset. So i can use one field for name, age and gender in the detail section.

Comment: The 2-step process is to export the result from the solution I provided above to a text file to be used as a CSV data source for a second report. 
Alternatively, you can use a UFL to write the data from the solution to any number of data sources (TEXT, CSV, Excel, Database Table via SQL). And use that as a 2nd data source. If you use a UFL, you can combine the 2 steps into a single report.